# While making ggplot axis title, how do I write £^-1?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to label the axis of my plot with £^-1. It does not seem to generate the desired output.

My code for yaxis is:

```
ylab(bquote('Carbon cost of earning ('*g.£^-1*')'))+
```

I received the error:

```
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

But the same code if run as:

```
ylab(bquote('Carbon cost of earning ('*g.GBP^-1*')'))+
```

I am able to get the desired output.
Any suggestions on how to make the pound symbol appear?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in `bquote` require quotes wrapped w/ tilde separator. So try

```
ylab(bquote("Carbon cost of earning (g.£"^-1 ~")"))
```

Comment: Hey, with your suggestion, the output simply writes:
Carbon cost of earning ("*g.£^-1*" ~ )
as such and doesn't render it with the superscript.

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten  ~ "" to append ,something like this  ylab(bquote("Carbon cost of earning (g.£"^-1 ~")")) should work in that case. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of incorporating unicode to get the job done.
I added:

```
labs(y="Carbon cost of earning (g.£\U207B\U00B9)")+
```